# can't use React context hook with vite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, vite, react-context

I am using react context hook for a vite project. Here are the three files that I am using:

`createContext` file:

```
import { createContext } from "react";
const SearchContext = createContext();

export default SearchContext;
```

`contextProvider` file:

```
import { useReducer } from "react";
import SearchContext from "./SearchContext";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  city: undefined,
  dates: [],
  searchOption: {
  adult: undefined,
  childern: undefined,
  rooms: undefined,
},
};

const SearchReducer = (state, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {
  case "NEW_SEARCH":
    return action.playload;
  case "RESET_SEARCH":
    return INITIAL_STATE;
  default:
    return state;
 }
};

 const SearchContextProvider = (childern) => {
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(SearchReducer, 
INITIAL_STATE);

return (
<SearchContext.Provider
  value={{
    city: state.city,
    dates: state.dates,
    searchOption: state.searchOption,
    dispatch,
  }}
 >
  {props.childern}
</SearchContext.Provider>
 );
};

export default SearchContextProvider;
```

Main file:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import "./index.css";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import SearchContextProvider from 
"./context/SearchContextState";
  
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
<React.StrictMode>
 <BrowserRouter>
  <SearchContextProvider>
     <App />
   </SearchContextProvider>
 </BrowserRouter>
</React.StrictMode>
);
```

Whenever I run `npm run dev`, my project does not render. If I remove the `<SearchContextProvider>` component, my project runs correctly.

Did I do something wrong, or can I not use ContextHook in my vite projects? Please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 typos in the context component:

- The parameter should be `props` instead of `childern`
- In JSX should be `props.children` instead of `props.childern`

```
 const SearchContextProvider = (childern) => { // <-------- Should be props
   const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(SearchReducer, INITIAL_STATE);

   return (
   <SearchContext.Provider
     value={{
       city: state.city,
       dates: state.dates,
      searchOption: state.searchOption,
      dispatch,
    }}>
       {props.childern} {/* <--- Should be props.children */}
    </SearchContext.Provider>
   );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The change here is in the SearchContextProvider component where I've added parentheses () around the JSX being returned. Without these parentheses, the function body becomes just a block of code without a return statement, and that's why your app might not be rendering as expected.